# How to print all the defined symbols in Coq?

Tags: coq

Is there a way to print all the available (existing at that point) symbols along with their types in Coq? I know about the `Print All.` query but it only seems to show symbols defined in the current script, excluding symbols that can be accessed/used (imported from some libraries), e.g. `eq_refl : forall (A : Type) (x : A), x = x`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found one solution: `Search _.` (searching with a wildcard)

Comment: That's one solution, another one may be to use a serialization protocol (such as SerAPI ;) ) , depending on your use case.

Comment: my user language is python and I imagine that i could interact with SerAPI (sending a `Search _.` command) via json?

Comment: SerAPI does provide more fine-grained `query` commands directly in its API so using search is not necessary. It depends what your use case is thou.

Comment: as stated in the question, i do want to obtain all symbols available in the context. `Search _.` feels like a hack. Is there a better query you would suggest for that effect?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, in the Coq "toplevel", `Search _` is all that you have, and you will get a bunch of text. If you want to use a third party toplevel like coq-serapi, you can indeed do `(Query opts Search)` and you will get a structured representation. You could also do `(Query opts Notation)` etc... Basically it depends what information you need. It is very easy to add the query you need (open an issue at github) . The main difference is that SerAPI operates "outside" Coq whereas `Search _` does work from inside.

Comment: i think you were clear and I understood that. And yes, i would love to deal with parsed S-exp instead of the flat printout from coqtop. now, i am trying to figure out how to interact with SerAPI from a python program.

Comment: Cool! SerAPI is very experimental, feel free to open any request in the bugtracker and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @ejgallego: could you move your comments into a real answer? Since it obviously is a legitimate answer to the problem that Falcon was having. Maybe Falcon could reformulate their question with the additional information that they gave in the comments as well.